# Discord.js v14 Interaction failed when click, button still works

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Consider:

```
const { Client, Message, MessageEmbed, MessageActionRow, MessageSelectMenu } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: 'help',
    description: 'Help Commands',
    aliases: ['h'],
    emoji: '❓',
    userperm: ['SEND_MESSAGES'],
    botperm: ['SEND_MESSAGES'],
    /**
     * @param {Client} client
     * @param {Message} message
     * @param {String[]} args
     */
    run: async (client, message, args) => {
        try {
            const emojis = {
                config: '⚙️',
                developer: '',
                fun: '',
                games: '',
                guild: '',
                info: 'ℹ️',
                levelling: '⏫',
                moderation: '⚒️',
                owner: '',
                search: '',
                user: '',
                utility: '',
                welcoming: '',
            };
            const directories = [...new Set(client.commands.map(cmd => cmd.directory))];
            const formatString = str => `${str[0].toUpperCase()}${str.slice(1).toLowerCase()}`;

            const categories = directories.map(dir => {
                const getCommands = client.commands
                    .filter(cmd => cmd.directory === dir)
                    .map(cmd => {
                        return {
                            name: cmd.name || 'No Name',
                            description: cmd.description || 'No Description Provided',
                            emoji: cmd.emoji || '',
                        };
                    });

                return {
                    directory: formatString(dir),
                    commands: getCommands,
                };
            });

            const color = message.guild.me.displayHexColor;
            const embed = new MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle('Help Desk')
                .setThumbnail(client.user.displayAvatarURL({ size: 512 }))
                .setDescription(
                    'Please choose a category in the dropdown menu!\n\nFor information about usage, or something about commands, You can [Join Server](#) for more info!'
                )
                .setColor(color);

            const components = state => [
                new MessageActionRow().addComponents(
                    new MessageSelectMenu()
                        .setCustomId('help-menu')
                        .setPlaceholder('Please select a category')
                        .setDisabled(state)
                        .addOptions(
                            categories.map(cmd => {
                                return {
                                    label: cmd.directory,
                                    value: cmd.directory.toLowerCase(),
                                    description: `Commands from ${cmd.directory} category`,
                                    emoji: { name: emojis[cmd.directory.toLowerCase()] || null },
                                };
                            })
                        )
                ),
            ];

            const initialMessage = await message.channel.send({
                embeds: [embed],
                components: components(false),
            });

            const filter = interaction => interaction.user.id === message.author.id;

            const collector = message.channel.createMessageComponentCollector({
                filter,
                componentType: 'SELECT_MENU',
                max: 13,
            });

            collector.on('collect', interaction => {
                const [directory] = interaction.values;
                const category = categories.find(x => x.directory.toLowerCase() === directory);

                const categoryEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
                    .setTitle(`${emojis[directory.toLowerCase()]} ${formatString(directory)} Commands`)
                    .setThumbnail(client.user.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: 512 }))
                    .setDescription(`Here are the list of commands!`)
                    .setColor(color)
                    .addFields(
                        category.commands.map(cmd => {
                            return {
                                name: `${cmd.emoji} \`${cmd.name}\``,
                                value: cmd.description,
                                inline: true,
                            };
                        })
                    )
                    .setTimestamp();

                interaction.update({ embeds: [categoryEmbed] });
            });
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
            message.channel.send({
                content: 'Uh oh! Something unexcepted. Try to running command again!',
            });
        }
    },
};
```

Where does the error lie?

Comment: if you're receiving interaction failed on an interactioncreate but it works eventually it means you aren't responding to the interaction in time. You need to respond to an interaction within 3 seconds

Answer (score 0):

You need to defer the update. When a button is clicked, it updates so you have to do:

```js
// Your code ...
collector.on('collect', async interaction => {
  await interaction.deferUpdate();
// Your code ...
});

// Your code ...
```

After adding `await interaction.deferUpdate();`, it shouldn't say interaction failed and one important thing. This line must be very first line of the `collect` event listener, because it needs to get deferred before updating or sending anything as the interaction limit is 3 seconds.